# How to make my entire column data as user to login my application?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I got a user table with an "Email" column, is that anyway to make all email to be login user instead of manually adding them?

Example if I create a new record with Email "abc@gmail.com", then this email will be the "username" which use to login to my application

Comment: "make all the email of this column as my user" What does this mean? You want to update all of the records in this table to have your email address?

Comment: I want to make all the email in my record to be login user

Comment: The question is not clear. You could be talking about virtual columns, DML, or authentication schemes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how to *automatically* set the USERNAME column on your USER_TABLE to the value from the EMAIL column, whenever a row is inserted. If so, you probably want a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BI_USER_TABLE
before insert on USER_TABLE
for each row
begin
    :new.USERNAME := :new.EMAIL;
end;
/
```

But maybe you want to manually set all existing USERNAMEs to equal the EMAIL value. If so, you want an update statement.

```
update USER_TABLE set USERNAME = EMAIL;
```